# Screen flickers composing an answer from iPhone

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, iphone

Try to post a question or an answer in the iPhone and you will know what I  talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the WMD editor of some kind, based on the keypress event in JavaScript.

On the 3GS it's so fast that you actually don't notice it happening, which is why I had trouble reproducing it.

edit: we now do some very rudimentary mobile device detection, and **disable the WMD JavaScript editor** for mobile devices to prevent any problems. You can of course still post and edit and ask, there's just no real time preview of your markdown.

Answer (score 4):

I've noticed this behavior myself (3G firmware 3.0)

When I try to write an answer it will start jumping all around the screen and it can be pretty infuriating, one of the biggest reasons why I don't bother using SO on the iPhone very often.

**[Obligatory reference for a strong API for iPhone app development among other reasons].**

Comment: I don't use very frequently, but was boring installing 7

Comment: As far as the iphone app goes, I would much prefer webapp specific changes based on serving pages for the useragent. Google does this in a lot of places.

Comment: Same issue here. Makes me want to claw my eyes out.

Answer (score 2):

Posting an answer from my phone now. Mother of all that is holy, it looks like I'm playing pong on a chess board.