# While entering question on iPad, window keeps scrolling the text area out of view

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ipad, scrolling

Hello all-

I was trying to ask a question on SO using my iPad and as I was typing, the window kept repeatedly scrolling all the way back up to the top of the screen and jerking around, preventing me from seeing what I was typing.  This is currently happening right now as I ask this question too, so I apologize if there are any glaring typos.

This did not use to happen until right now, so I'm guessing it's a recent regression.  Could someone look into this and try to get it fixed?  It's making the site really hard to use on my iPad.

Thanks so much!

Comment: See: [Everything is grayscale on my iPad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81108/everything-is-grayscale-on-my-ipad/81114#81114) - *"I hope Mobile Safari has fixed their WMD issues..."* (and see also: [Screen flickers composing an answer from iPhone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13103/screen-flickers-composing-an-answer-from-iphone))

Comment: @Shog9- The thing is that I've been using an iPad for months now without this ever coming up, and all of the sudden it just started up.  I may be missing this, but what's the connection between the iPhone screen flickering and the iPad input messing up?

Comment: @templatetypedef: my *guess* (and I can't test this) is that this is a bug with Mobile Safari caused by the recent return to the full version of the site for iPads.

Comment: @Templatetypedef - are you using the latest iOS for your iPad? I am testing with version 4.2.1 and don't see this.

Comment: we can't reproduce this. Can you specify what version of iOS?

Comment: I am using 3.2 and it has only started to happen to me this march. It does not happen to comment section. Only in ask a question and answer rich input boxes. I type and the window scrolls to top so I can't see where I am typing.

Comment: Yup... I had an old version if iOS (3.2, I believe).  Just updated to 4.3 and now it works just great.  Sorry for taking so long to get back to you about this!

Comment: When you click on the preview text while typing a question/answer, it tries to scroll up incoherently (at least in Firefox), which is rather annoying to me.  Think this might be related?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this behavior elsewhere, but don't recall seeing it on so.

Testing on an iPad with 4.2.1 right now, I can't reproduce the problem for questions or answers.

Comment: It is happening in iPad 3.2 iOS